# representing the name of variables in a scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I need to write a function which draws a plot for the variables.  The problem is that it doesn't print the name of variables.

```
visual<-function( x , y){      
   df<-cbind(x,y)
   df<-scale(df, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
   df<-as.data.frame(df)
   ggpairs(df, columns=1:2,xlab = colnames(df)[1],ylab =colnames(df)[2])
}
```

If we have these to vectors:

```
a <- c(128.095014,  71.430997,  88.704595,  48.180638)
b <- c(10.584888,  10.246740,   4.422322,   9.621246)
visual(a,b)
```

What is wrong with that?

Comment: Where is `ggpairs` from?  Is that from a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substitute` to get the names of the objects passed into your function.

```
visual<-function(x, y){
  xname <- substitute(x)
  yname <- substitute(y)

  df<-cbind(x,y)

  df<-scale(df, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)

  df<-as.data.frame(df)

  names(df) <- c(xname, yname)

  GGally::ggpairs(df, columns=1:2, xlab = colnames(df)[1], ylab =colnames(df)[2])
}

b<-c(128.095014,  71.430997,  88.704595,  48.180638)
a<-c(10.584888,  10.246740,   4.422322,   9.621246)

visual(a,b)
```

#### output

[image: ggpairs plot output]

Comment: Thank you very much. That was awesome.